# How to Download multiple files in sketchware?

Tags: sketchware

How do I download multiple files in a queue one by one! In sketchware

Please let me know how to do that.

Sketchware

Answer (score 0):

Just download files when first you are downloading is the first in queue; you can pause first and run the second download. Then, while the second was downloading and first is stopped, check if 2 was downloaded, then unpause 1.

**You can use these blocks:**

[image: view]